# How can I customize the map and remove the 'POI Layer'?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On the embedded Google map (e.g. here - https://www.familienfreunde.de/4.php?Nummer=132700000302) you can see a lot of Point of Interest.

I would like to remove them.

```
<script>
function initMap() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.3267379,12.3653812);
  var myOptions = {
 zoom: 19,
 center: latlng,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 mapTypeIds: ["roadmap", "satellite"]
}
 };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  var box_html = "<h5>Gymnasium Gerda Taro Schule</h5><p>04107 Leipzig<br /><b><a href=\"4.php?Nummer=132700000302\">Profil anzeigen</a></b></p>";
  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/bilder/marker4.png'); 
  var marker = add_marker(51.3267379,12.3653812,'Gymnasium Gerda Taro Schule',box_html,icon);
  marker.setMap(map);
        var box_html = "<h5>Rechtsanwalt Henry Bach</h5><p>04107 Leipzig<br /><b><a href=\"22.php?Nummer=378\">Profil anzeigen</a></b></p>";
  var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/bilder/marker22.png'); 
  var marker = add_marker(51.3339224,12.3741322,'Rechtsanwalt Henry Bach',box_html,icon);
  marker.setMap(map); }
function add_marker(lat,lng,title,box_html,icon) {
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: box_html
   });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      map: map,
      icon: icon,
      title: title
    });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
    infowindow.close();
   });
     return marker;
    }
</script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=UNSERKEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

(I have only removed some more markers for the sake of clarity.)

Comment: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ - Set POI visibility to `hidden`.

Comment: oh, damn it.

Then I'm using the wrong API. Then I have to rebuild all the code and read the documentation first.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not using the wrong API. You just need to add styling to your map instance. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: @MrUpsidown it is three years later and this does not work with map ids for static maps. The examle loses them but the returned map still has them.

Comment: @mckenzm what are you talking about? It works fine and it is all [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/cloud-customization/overview).

Comment: @MrUpsidown with the caveat that it works for JavaScript API.  I lied a little bit, I can make the POI go avay by double scaling(2) and then resizing the image back. It is not lossless.  It may also be the locality.  This is for static using https, no JS.  Using a MAP ID and style modified with POI slider.

Comment: @mckenzm I have no idea what you are talking about. If you have a question, open a new question and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try seeting the visibility of POI off using styles  property

```
    function initMap() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.3267379,12.3653812);
      var myOptions = {
     zoom: 19,
     center: latlng,
     styles = [
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ];
     mapTypeControlOptions: {
     mapTypeIds: ["roadmap", "satellite"]
    }
```

Comment: according to styles i replaced the = with a :.

And at the end the ; by a ,

Now it's working. Thank you very much.